# Getting Undefined Subscribe and cannot spy the oninit method as how to spy applicationstate service as it is not a function in Angular

Tags: angular, subscribe, spy

My onit function

```
ngonInit(): void {

  this.environmentName= this.environment.getGlobalEnvironment.environmentName;

this.applicationStateService.LanguageCodeObserver.subscribe((LanguageCode: string) { this.appLanguage languageCode;

 this.applicationStateService.publishIsHideRegister Header (false);

}
```

I am not able to write the unit test for my ngonit function as it contains a subscribe method which doesn't have a function in any service.ts so that I can spy that method ,  it's a behavioral subject.So how can I write unit test as I am getting error on that line subscribe of undefined. I have added the screenshot image too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy0mZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add the error you getting
2. You need to create a Mock for your service in the spec. After you add it correctly to the mock in the spec file, you can spy on it.
3. The test approach is to run the method and expect that the service called with false.

   expect(applicationStateService.object.publishIsHideRegister).tohavebeencalledwith(false)

something like that

Comment: this.applicationStateService.LanguageCodeObserver.subscribe((LanguageCode: string) { this.appLanguage languageCode }.         How can write the test case for this line , facing the issue here.

Comment: this.applicationStateService.LanguageCodeObserver.subscribe((LanguageCode: string) =>{
expect(LanguageCode).toequal())
done() /// add this at the staring of the test read about doneFn
}

Comment: I haven't replied you earlier due to some problem with my account.Hi I have  tried with your solution but it throughs me a error expected a spy but got languageCode. So i am still stuck on this.

Comment: no problem it as expected you need yo add spyOn to that function. Read about "spyOn" .

add before the subscribe

spyOn<any>(this.applicationStateService,"LanguageCodeObserver");

Comment: But this subscribe does not a function, it is done in such a way that for spy on I cannot understand which part I will give in the function part.